# Is there a way to make preprocessor definitions in vimrc?

Tags: vimscript, vimrc

I'd like to create a new symbol to use in my vimrc that's `<normal>`, so I do not have to type `<C-\><C-N>` to get to do the "go to normal mode" command, nor clutter the vimrc file with combinations that I might not remember.

**In C it would have been done with `#define`, how is this done in VimL?**

C like example:

```
#define <normal> <C-\><C-N>

nmap <leader>q <normal>@q
```

instead of

```
nmap <leader>q <C-\><C-N>@q
```

Comment: Note that I do not wish to use abbreviations or mappings, since these will replace the text.

Comment: I presume you're deliberately using `<C-\><C-N>` instead of <Esc> because you don't like the beep? Also, surely an nmap means you'll already be in normal mode? Is that just a typo, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

VimL doesn't have preprocessor macros.  You can still do it, sort of, but I'm afraid it's a case of a medicine being worse than the disease it's supposed to cure:

```viml
let normal = '<C-\><C-N>'
exe 'nmap <leader>q ' . normal . '@q'
```